# Duplicate elements in list having the same index

Tags: python, duplicates

I'm a beginner trying this Python exercise:

Write a Python program to print all even numbers from a given numbers list in the same order and stop the printing for any numbers that come after 237 in the sequence.

Sample numbers list : [
386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 958, 743, 527]

Here's my attempt:

```
def even_numbers(num_list):
    for num in num_list:
        mod = num % 2
        if mod == 0 and num_list.index(num) < num_list.index(237):  # this is supposed to get the even numbers and stop printing at "237"
            print(num)

even_numbers([386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 399,
              162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 815, 67, 
              104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 958, 743, 527])

Notice there are 2 "566" elements, one coming before "237", the other coming after.
```

Here's the output I got:
`386 462 418 344 236 566 978 328 162 758 918 566`
The last "566" element in the output shouldn't be there because it comes after "273". But since there are two "566" elements, it seems that Python thinks the second one shares the same index as the first.

What should I do to get rid of the last "566" element in the output?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing anything with indexes at all, you should simply `break` out of the loop if the value 237 is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this issue:

1. Break out of the loop when 237 is encountered
2. Modify the logic of finding the index of the current number

Breaking out of the loop is cleaner, short circuits the process yielding better performance and also allows us to remove the index checking.

If there is no searching done after 237, there's no way you can get any number printed regardless of if it's a duplicate or not:

```
def even_numbers(num_list):
    for num in num_list:
        if num == 237:
           break
        mod = num % 2
        if mod == 0:
            print(num)
```

---

Solution 1 is much better however for the sake of completeness, it's good to know that `index(str)` also accepts another parameter.

[`start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) lets you specify the beginning of the search based on a starting index.

The trick here is to keep a running start index so that when it comes to `num_list.index(num)` for the duplicate of 566, the first 566 is not included in the search:

```
def even_numbers(num_list):
    start_at = -1
    for num in num_list:
        mod = num % 2
        if mod == 0 and num_list.index(num, start_at + 1) < num_list.index(237):
            print(num)
            start_at += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, your first method works perfectly. The second one yields an error, though I kind of understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @KhorJiaWynn Oops, sorry - should work now. No worries!